# Check likes counts periodically on post made by FB App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I developing an app that allows users to post content to their wall, when they post to the site. However, can the app go and check the no. of likes and shares periodically without the user involved in the process?

Comment: The question is not very clear. Can you please elaborate?